# How to attack sql injection when a program PHP have function mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

```
//...
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$str = mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
$query = "SELECT * FROM thread WHERE sub_title LIKE '%". $str ."%' LIMIT 20";
```

Thanks for reply.